# cascading dropdownlist with out reload page

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to cascade second dropdown without page reload on selecting first dropdown
without autopostback in dropdown

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropcaste" Width="128px" runat=server AutoPostBack=true
                                onselectedindexchanged="dropcaste_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>


 protected void dropcaste_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string select = dropcaste.SelectedItem.Value;
        con = new SqlConnection(str);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select c.castename,s.subcastename from subcastemaster_mrg s inner join castemas_mrg c on(s.castecode=c.castecode) where c.castecode=" + select + "", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        subcastegrid.DataSource = dt;
        subcastegrid.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
```